# Autoprefixer is causing node-sass source map to point to the wrong files

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, source-maps, autoprefixer

I built a custom Node script that does all of my SCSS processing manually in JS rather than through the command line or with webpack.

The process is as follows:

1. Watch .scss files for changes.
2. On change, compile the SCSS to CSS with `node-sass` and generate a source map with `node-sass` at the same time.
3. Write the `screen.css` and `screen.css.map` file using `fs.writeFile()
4. For the `screen.css` file, I then re-read it with `fs.readFile` to get the buffer, and run the CSS contents through `postcss` using the `autoprefixer` plugin to autoprefix all of the CSS. I then re-write this using `fs.writeFile` again and finally upload it to the server using `jsftp`. At the same time, the process for the `screen.css.map` file is the exact same, except that I don't run it through `postcss`, I just re-read it and upload it to the server after the initial writing.

**My problem**

If I include the `autoprefixer` plugin when using `postcss`, e.g:

```
postcss([autoprefixer]).process(buffer, {
    from: "assets/css/screen.css",
    to: "assets/css/screen.css"
}).then(result => {...})
```

the sourcemap is completely wrong when inspecting in the browser and points to not only the wrong lines but also the wrong files.

For example, the SCSS for the page banner is in `_banner.scss`, but the sourcemap tells me it is all in `_calendar.scss`.

However if I keep all of the code the exact same but leave out `autoprefixer`, e.g:

```
postcss([]).process(buffer, {
    from: "assets/css/screen.css",
    to: "assets/css/screen.css"
}).then(result => {...})
```

The sourcemap works perfectly, pointing me correctly to `_banner.scss` for all the banner styles.

Has anyone got any idea how I can fix this and get my SCSS sourcemaps working whilst still using autoprefixer?

Link to full sourcecode for the SCSS processing node script here, ignore the horrible nesting, this is just an early version :) https://github.com/JJGerrish/twk-boilerplate/blob/master/template/style.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who needs it I found a fix.

Basically, `postcss` has an option to detect a previous source map and use it for it's own source map instead of generating a new one.

I found this solution on a GitHub issue that did the trick for me, basically, you have to get the `node-sass` generated source map, stringify it, and then pass it to the `postcss` `map` option object.

https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/222#issuecomment-318136962

Code below incase link disappears:

```
postcss([autoprefixer])
    .process(result.css, {
        from: "assets/css/screen.css",
        to: "assets/css/screen.css",
        map: {
            prev: result.map.toString(),
            inline: false,
        },
    })
    .then(result => {...})
```

Comment: Hi i have no from, to config in my scss.js task. can you please help me regarding this?